# Can't edit the roles of the users in the easyAdminBundle .yml symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4, easyadmin

```
easy_admin:
entities:
    User:
        class: App\Entity\User
        disabled_actions: ['new']
        avatar_property_path: 'picture'
        form:
            fields:
                - {property: 'rank'}
                - { property: 'roles',
                    type: choice,type_options: { mapped: true, expanded: true, multiple: true},
                    choices: [role_admin: 'ROLE_ADMIN' , role_user: 'ROLE_USER'] }
```

*this is the code that i wrote  and this is the result :*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi4w5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like this instead of form

```
easy_admin:
entities:
    User:
        class: App\Entity\User
        disabled_actions: ['new']
        avatar_property_path: 'picture'
        new:
            fields:
                - {property: 'rank'}
                - { property: 'roles',
                    type: choice,type_options: { mapped: true, expanded: true, multiple: true},
                    choices: [role_admin: 'ROLE_ADMIN' , role_user: 'ROLE_USER'] }
        edit:
                fields:
                    - {property: 'rank'}
                    - { property: 'roles',
                        type: choice,type_options: { mapped: true, expanded: true, multiple: true},
                        choices: [role_admin: 'ROLE_ADMIN' , role_user: 'ROLE_USER'] }
```

Comment: because currently i'm working on project that i'm using easyadmin for it, i did the same thing and its working can you create a github Gist and share you easyadmin file so i can help you @Labmember

Comment: Thanks alot for help here is the gist https://gist.github.com/Labmember7/48d341012aeb6fc9632ac8784ceca10c

Comment: if you have any small project exemple using easyadmin and modifing the roles of the users pls let me know i searched for days but no result :( and  i really appreciate your help

Comment: i can fix your problem if you share your project or only your app with user and easyadmin , right now i don't have a project, but i'm 100% sure i can help you

Comment: thanks alot i've finally found the correct syntax here it is https://gist.github.com/Labmember7/48d341012aeb6fc9632ac8784ceca10c

Comment: btw do you know any easy way to publish my symfony application for free

Comment: Nice job, unfortunately i don’t know how to publish symfony for free:(

Comment: Thanks. I had an issue when saving new roles: the roles (json format) was saved as an object instead of an array. Adding 'array_values' in the setRoles(roles) method like:
$this->roles = array_values($roles) solved this. This re-indexes the array, and the result is stored as an array in json